# Problem with proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have n elements for a total value of 100.

I have m elements of the n elements each one has a value that is 80% of the value of each other n-m element. With m <= n.

How can I calculate the value of one of the m elements ?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  "$80\%$ of the value of each other $n-m$ elements."  doesn't mean anything.  Can you work the case $n=2$ or is that somehow not an allowed case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that each of the other $n-m$ elements has value $v$. Then each of the $m$ elements has value $0.8v$, and the total value of all $n$ elements is

$$100=m(0.8)v+(n-m)v=(n+0.8m-m)v=(n-0.2m)v\;,$$

so

$$v=\frac{100}{n-0.2m}\;.$$

The value of one of the $m$ elements is $80$% of that, or

$$0.8v=\frac{80}{n-0.2m}\;.$$